# Descend Sort Expression in Cloud Search AWS Suggest

Tags: amazon-web-services

I try to control sort expression into AWS Cloud Search Suggesters, i create one index "int_timestamp" its int witch time event.

I like to order my suggesters in descend do int_timestamp.

PS: A have one domain, this domain have a index "txt_event", its a string with name, suggesters using this field do index.

Answer (score 0):

For AWS CloudSearch suggester, you can only sort by giving it a sort expression.  It has to be a numeric sort enabled field from the domain. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-expressions.html

It is already in descending order.  For example:  I sort my suggester with a popularity int field.  The first suggestion will be the highest popularity number.

If you want ascending field, you have to create an expression like 1000 - popularity in order to invert the numbers.  But keep in mind, this will cause the indexing of the suggester to be really slow.